# How to fetch value from database in beetween the date range using PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

I need to extract values within the date range and group by some other value.

I have the input `date=2016-10-21`. I need to fetch all data between the date range (date_from and date_to). The values should be grouped by `subcat_id` and those the rows that have blank date_from or date_to field should be ignored.

```
$date='2016-10-21';
$sql="select * from db_details where date_from>='".$date."' and date_to <= '".$date."' group by subcat_id ";
```

---

```
id    subcat_id   subcat_name     date_from          date_to    
1         62         ddd          2016-10-22         2016-10-26    
2         62         ddd          2016-10-22         2016-10-26    
3         62         ddd                                            
4         63         sss          2016-10-18         2016-10-21    
5         63         sss          2016-10-18         2016-10-21    
6         64         fff          2016-10-20         2016-10-25
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: select * from table where date_from>= 'date' and date_to <='date 2'

Comment: select * from table where date_from between $date1 and $date2

Comment: 'i was trying like this "select * from db_details where date_from>='".$date."' and date_to <= '".$date."' group by subcat_id " 'but its not giving any value.

Comment: @RafaelShkembi: I have to group also the value.

Comment: `where date_from>='".date."'...` so where is the `$` ? as in `where date_from>='".$date."' ...` if you defined that and how.

Comment: yes, here $date='2016-10-21'.

Comment: There is no problem with the group by. The problem is in your query syntax. please post your query in your script

Comment: I see you edited your comment now to include the `$` signs. Why don't you post your full code in the question, rather than commenting? and others guessing.

Comment: select * from table where date_from between $date1 and $date2

Comment: I have tested my query is not showing any syntax error .

Comment: where is your query and did you use mysqli_error?

Comment: @mhmd : what is $date1 and $date2.

Comment: if you're not going to post your code, then I for one won't stand around here staring at this screen to see if and when you did. We don't even know if you are checking for errors via php/mysql.

Comment: $date1 and $date2 the two date you want to select between

Comment: @Fred-ii- : I have posted my query.

Comment: and you've an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the comments, your problem is your query:

```
select * from db_details where date_from>='".date."' and date_to <= '".date."' group by subcat_id
```

First, you dont need to cancat (.date.) in the query, simply plugging in the `$variable` will work.

Second, you aren't actually plugging anything into your query. You are searching for, literally, everything between the word `.date.` and the word `.date.`

Your query should look like this:

```
select * from db_details where date_from>=$date_from and date_to <= $date_to group by subcat_id
```

As a suggestion, you should probably upgrade to mysqli, or if you have, you should use [named placeholders](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Please check my updated post .Here i need to fetch all value using the given input date . that date should lies between the date range.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong:

```
SELECT * FROM db_details WHERE date_from >= :date AND date_to <= :date GROUP BY subcat_id
```

This reads as: The specified date is *before* the from-date and *after* the to-date. If the from-date is always before the to-date, this is an impossible condition: it will never match any rows.

You want something like:

```
SELECT * FROM db_details WHERE date_from <= :date AND date_to >= :date GROUP BY subcat_id
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM db_details WHERE :date BETWEEN date_from AND date_to GROUP BY subcat_id
```

Comment: If the date_from and date_to value is blank those should be ignored.

Comment: @subhra So add conditions for that.

Comment: i have value like this `$date='2016-10-21'` . While i am putting like this `date_from <= :date AND date_to >= :date` .its not coming.

Comment: @subhra This is the syntax for a prepared statement in PDO. If you are using mysqli you can use question marks instead of the `:date` placeholder I am using. Either way I would always recommend using a prepared statement to avoid mistakes leading to sql injection.

Comment: i did this.THank you.